# How to shift voltage label down?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, circuitikz

How can I move $V_L$ down? I checked previous posts but none of them work. Probably I missed something
1.`v^=\raisebox{-10ex}{$V_L$}` doesn't seem to work with negative number.  
2.`voltage shift = -1` this does shift $V_L$ but it also shifts the plus and minus signs which is not desired.  
3. I think just remove all the voltage + plus/minus signs together and then manually place them but that seems too much work for a beginner like me.

Is there a simple way to just shift $V_L$ down?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[american, siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) to [cute inductor, v^=$V_L$] ++(3,0);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Interestingly, \raisebox will not reduce the depth.  (e.g. `\strut\fbox{\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{$V_L$}}`)  I wonder if this is new?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[american, siunitx]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) to[cute inductor, v^=$V_L$] ++(3,0);
\draw (0,-2) to[cute inductor, v^=$V_L$, voltage/american label distance=0.8pt] ++(3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Two inductors with labels]

Comment: well nice, is it really that simple?

Comment: You will probably want to set the option inside `\ctikzset{...}`, so that it is applied to all of your circuit.

Comment: Probably manually set that is ok as until now I only have an example where I need to shift it down a bit to fit in a box.

Comment: `\draw (-0.3,0.4) to [V, v^=$V_S$, voltage/american label distance=-2.5pt] (-0.3,2.4); `
Unfortunately, this one doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `\draw (-0.3,0.4) to[V, v=$V_S$, voltage shift=-0.8pt] (-0.3,2.4);`

Comment: I see. I prefer making label consistent to using this voltage shift.

Answer (score 4):

Tikz nodes center the text based on the height and depth, not the baseline.  `\raisebox` normally adjusts the height to match the new location, but we want Tikz to think it hasn't moved.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[american, siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) to [cute inductor, v^={\raisebox{-6ex}[\height][\depth]{$V_L$}}] ++(3,0);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. If the OP wants to place `$V_L$` just above instead of below the coil, use `-1ex` rather than `-6ex`.